# Как отрисовать черную линию вверху экрана

Tags: css

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите пожалуйста новичку как нарисовать горизонтальную линию на сайте вверху экрана которая идет через всю страницу. Как пример этот сайт: http://nwoil.org/. Здесь линия уходит вверх вместе с прокруткой.

И второй вариант синяя горизонтальная линия вверху экрана как в фейсбуке.

Код html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Горизонтальная линия</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styletest.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <div id="line">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Код css:

```
#line {
    border-top: solid;
}
```

Данный код не подходит тем что отрисовывает линию где видно начало и конец, а так же имеется отступ сверху. Хотелось бы видеть линию как на www.facebook.com, верхняя синяя линия. Которая во всю ширину страницы (не видно фона сверху и по бокам. Необходимо сделать ее как будто фоновой

Comment: В сайте по вашей ссылке просто же свойство `border-top` задано к контейнеру. А что в фейсбуке за линия? В смысле меню плавающее?

Comment: Что касается первого сайта как примерно будет выглядеть код? И что касается ФБ - да меню. Спасибо!!!

Comment: Вам азы css и html нужно изучить. А для получения кода для добавлении линии на сайт создайте заказ на фрилансе.

Comment: Так я сам учусь этому. Зачем же мне заказ. Я не зарабатываю не этом. Всего лишь попросил помочь сочувствующих. Но если мы уже докатились до того чтобы вместо небольшой помощи (уверен там всего пара строчек) отправлять на фриланс тогда печально господа.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Ссылки могут служить только дополнением к вопросу, вся необходимая информация должна располагаться **непосредственно** в вопросе

Comment: @VitalyVitaly, не в комментариях, а в **вопросе** - под вопросом есть кнопка _"править"_ - нажав ее можно отредактировать свой вопрос

Comment: Исправил вопрос.

Comment: @VitalyVitaly, теперь стоит добавить в сам вопрос, чем код, который там приведен не подходит

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1em solid blue;
}
```

Comment: ну ты б хоть написал про `margin:0` :)

Comment: @Grundy, а что про него написать?

Comment: Что отступы были из-за него :-) а не просто так :-)

Comment: Господа, а как задать обратно margin по умолчанию браузера? Теперь он всю страницу делает на всю ширину негодяй. Спасибо

Comment: @VitalyVitaly, `body { margin: 8px; }`

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо! В общем мне еще учиться и учиться )

Comment: @VitalyVitaly, прими ответ нажатием галочки слева.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте параметров к стилю

```
#line {
    border-top: 5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Этот код дает линию которая имеет отступы от верхней и боковых частей. Обратите внимание на сайт https://www.facebook.com/. Верхняя синяя линия. Она как-бы не имеет начала и конца, во всю! длину страницы.

Comment: Так откройте режим разработчика, и посмотрите, откуда там отступы! Скорее всего, сброс стилей не подключен, и это стандартные стили браузера дают эти отступы. Потрите их, и все. UPD - клавиша F12. UPD2 - и посмотрите на код, Вами приведенный. Где закрытый хед, где открытый боди?!

Comment: Юрий! Вы святой человек! Буду в церкви поставлю свечку за здравие! ))) в коде они как-то не уместились. Сам код правильный. Спасибо!

Comment: @Юрий_Смирнов, стоит добавить информацию из комментария в ответ

Answer (score -1):

У вас в `html` коде, нет закрывающего тега `head` и нет открывающего тега `body` и `border-top` не полностью написан.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#line {
  border-top: solid 2px #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Горизонтальная линия</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styletest.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="line">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: это не ошибка, браузеры позволяют довольно много вольностей с разметкой

Comment: @Grundy, это вообще не ошибка, стандарт разрешает их не писать.

Comment: Причина не в тегах.

Comment: @Qwertiy, так я и написал - что не ошибка :-)

Comment: В сниппете не надо писать разметку doctype/html/body - всё написанное помещается в body.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не все, половина вырезается

Comment: Я использовал код из вопроса, чтобы спрашивающему было понятней.

Answer (score -1):

границу можно назначить любому объекту, даже `<html>`

```css
html {
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}
```